# BeanStalk configuration lost after rebooting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk environment running ruby 1.9.3 and passenger.

After rebooting the instance all configuration is lost, what can I do to persist my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your configuration: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.saving.html